# php write in a file double quote from variable

Tags: php, json, html, double-quotes

I'm having problems when I try to write `doble quotes` from a variable into a text file. When a piece of text comes with a `" text "` the file is not created. I tried several things but nothing seems to work. By now I have to avoid write `double quotes`.

Here is my code in `PHP` :

```
<?php 

  $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
  $name = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
  $url_to = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['url_to']));
  $saveToFile = $url_to . $name . '.srt';

  $space = "\n";
  $blank = " ";
  $arrow = " --> ";

  if (isset($data))
  {

  $h = fopen($saveToFile, 'w+');
  if ($h) {
    foreach ($data as $sub) {
        fwrite($h,$sub->number);
        fwrite($h,$space);
        fwrite($h,$sub->start);
        fwrite($h,$arrow);
        fwrite($h,$sub->end);
        fwrite($h,$space);
        if(strpos($sub->text,'"')!==false){
            $sub->text = str_replace('"',"'",$sub->text);
            fwrite($h,$sub->text);
        } else {
            fwrite($h,$sub->text);
        }
        fwrite($h,$space);
        fwrite($h,$space);
    }
    fclose($h);
  }
  exit('Data Saved.');
 }
?>
```

To clarify some things: I get the text from a "stringified" JSON variable coming from a HTML5 front end page, and I write this text to a file, but if it comes with a double quote, nothing is written.

thanks

Comment: Probably it's failing at the very first line. Debug! Figure out where exactly it "fails". The cause is likely that you're destroying your JSON by using `stripslashes`.

Comment: Oh, it worked! I have a lot to learn yet... Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just to be clear, writing PHP today, you should never need to use `stripslashes()`. The functionality that added slashes automatically (and thus required stripping them) has been removed from modern versions of PHP. Make sure you're using an up-to-date PHP version, and make sure you're learning from up-to-date tutorials -- things have changed a *lot* in PHP over the last ten years, so if you're reading old tutorials that suggest using `stripslashes()` then you're probably doing lots of other things wrong as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)